# Limit of quotient in the number of combinatorial sequences involving Fibonacci numbers

Tags: combinatorics, limits, discrete-mathematics

Let's call $a_n$ the number of sequences of length $n$ of $\{0,1,2,3,4\}$. Let $x_k$ denote the kth digit in the sequence ($k\in\{1,2,...n\}$). We want this sequence to be 'alternating' which in this case means:
$$
\begin{align}
\\x_k\in \{1,3\} \implies x_{k+1} \notin \{1,3\}
\\x_k\in \{2,4\} \implies x_{k+1} \notin \{2,4\}
\\x_k = 0 \implies x_{k+1} \neq 0
\end{align}
$$

i.e. A 0 cannot be followed by a zero, an even digit (greater than 0) cannot be followed by another even digit and an odd digit cannot be followed by another odd digit.

I want to find $\lim_{n\to\infty}{\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}}$

If there are no zeros, $a_n = 2^{n+1}$ because we can choose 4 digits in the first position and then 2 in each subsequent position.

If we add a zero in any position except the first or last the number of sequnces is the same, this is because we split the sequence into two independent ones of lengths $k$ and $n-k-1$, giving us $2^{k+1}\cdot 2^{n-k}=2^{n+1}$.

Thus we need to count the number of ways to place 0 and deal with the edge cases. For $n$ available positions the number of ways to place zeros without any two being adjacent is equal $F_{n+2}$, which is the n+2th Fibonacci number.

Thus to find all sequences we split the problem into 4 cases:

1. Sequences that don't start or end in 0
2. Sequences that start but don't end in a 0
3. Sequences that end but don't start in a 0
4. Sequences that both start and end in a zero

For 1. for a sequence of length $n\geq 3$ we get $2^{n+1}F_n$. Because we can place a zero in all but 2 positions, let's call this count of sequences $b_n$.

For 2. and 3. is the same as above but we append a 0 and the beginning or end, so we get $2b_{n-1}=2\cdot2^{n}F_{n-1}$.

For 4. we append a zero at both ends so we get $b_{n-2}=2^{n}F_{n-1}$

From this I concluded that:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}{\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}{\frac{b_{n+1}+2b_n+b_{n-1}}{b_{n}+2b_{n-1}+b_{n-2}}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}{\frac{2^n(4F_{n+1}+4F_n+F_{n-1})}{2^{n-1}(4F_n+4F_{n-1}+F_{n-2})}=\lim_{n\to\infty}{\frac{8F_{n+1}+8F_n+2F_{n-1}}{4F_n+4F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}}}}
$$

Writing this out with the closed form formula for Fibonacci numbers leads me to believe that I either do not know of a technique to solve such a limit or that there is a mistake in the combinatorial argument.

Comment: This is not clear.  What is $a_n$?  Are you defining it to be the number of words of length $n$ based on $5$ characters?  So, $a_n=5^n$?  Something else?  And what is $x_k$?  It's not clear which "digits" you are talking about....

Comment: The digits we can use are 0,1,2,3 and 4. So there are 5 characters. Sequences such as 00, 13, 24 are incorrect whilst something like 202, 123, 301.

Comment: Yes, I corrected that typo. So $a_n=5^n$?

Comment: Sorry I edited the response above and the question, I didn't know pressing enter submitted an answer

Comment: Ok, so the $a_n$ only counts the words with some special properties.  Surely there are simple recursions satisfied by the $a_n$, right?  I suggest, compute the first hundred or so of the $a_n$ and evaluate the limit numerically.  It always helps to know the answer before trying to prove it.

Comment: Indeed, is it not the case that $a_n=4\times a_{n-1}$?  If I have understood the rules (certainly not clear), then this is easily proven.

Comment: It doesn't work e.g. when $n=2$. A sequence of length 1 can have any of the digits. For sequences of length 2 we can have all 25 unrestricted sequences except:
{00} {odd, odd} {even, even}
which leaves us with 16 sequences.

Comment: Right, I had a bug.  Having fixed the bug, the sequence of the $a_n$ that I get is $\{5,16,52,168,544, \cdots\}$ and the limit of the ratios is $3.236$ (numerically).

Comment: Which is twice the golden ratio.

Comment: Yeah, that's the answer I got before taking into account the edge cases with zeros at the beginning and end. Which would imply we can disregard the lower order terms in the numerator and denominator. I can't justify why though.

Comment: My approach:  Let $A_n$ be the count of the good words beginning with $1$ or $3$, $B_n$ counts those beginning with $2,4$, and $C_n$ counts those beginning with $0$.  Then each of those, and therefore the $a_n$,  satisfies the recursion $s_n=2s_{n-1}+4s_{n-2}$.  That's easily solved in its own right, though (as you remark) you can connect it to the Fibonacci numbers.  I don't see the advantage of that, however.  Just use the closed form solution.

Comment: To clarify:  you keep referring to "even" and "odd" but that isn't what you mean (assuming I understand correctly, which I now believe I do).  $0$ is an even number but you don't want to include it as "even" here.  That's why I switched to $A_n,B_n, C_n$.  My $A_n$ is what you call odd, and $B_n$ is what you call even, and the $C_n$ just start with $0$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $A_n$ count the good words of length $n$ that start with $1$ or $3$.

Let $B_n$ count the good words of length $n$ that start with $2$ or $4$.

Let $C_n$ count the good words of length $n$ that start with $0$.

Clearly, $a_n=A_n+B_n+C_n$ and $A_n=B_n$

Recursively:  $$C_n=A_{n-1}+B_{n-1}=2A_{n-1}$$   and $$A_n=2(B_{n-1}+C_{n-1})=2(A_{n-1}+C_{n-1})=2(A_{n-1}+2A_{n-2})=2A_{n-1}+4A_{n-2}$$

It is easy to see that $C_n$ follows the same recursion, and it follows from that that $a_n$ does as well.

That's all we need!  The characteristic polynomial for that recursion is $$x^2=2x+4$$

which has roots $1\pm \sqrt 5$.  We could get closed forms for the $a_n$ and the others but there is no need.  $|1+\sqrt 5|>|1-\sqrt 5|$ so the desired limit is $$\boxed {1+\sqrt 5}$$

Side note:  without having thought about it at any length, it's not instantly clear to me how to show combinatorially that $a_n$ satisfies the recursion.  The argument I give isn't difficult, but perhaps there is a direct way to see it.

For completeness, here is a closed form for the $a_n$:

$$a_n=\frac { (15 - 7 \sqrt 5) (1 - \sqrt 5)^n + (1 + \sqrt 5)^n (15 + 7 \sqrt 5)}{20}$$

Comment: (+1) Ah! I got the same answer, and didn't notice yours. I was about to type mine when I saw it.

Comment: @DS  If you have a more direct proof that $a_n$ satisfies the recursion, I'd suggest posting that.  My argument isn't especially difficult, but it's pretty indirect. I bet it can be improved.

Comment: no, mine is pretty much similar. The only difference is that your $A_n, B_n,C_n$ are my $o_n,e_n,z_n$ and that I define them as ending with the respective type rather than the starting.

Comment: @DS  Yeah...I mean, it really depends on the symmetry so maybe it can't be improved much.

Comment: For a similar argument: you have essentially showed that $\begin{bmatrix}A_n\\B_n\\C_n\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0&2&2\\2&0&2\\1&1&0\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}A_{n-1}\\B_{n-1}\\C_{n-1}\end{bmatrix}$.  That matrix should have characteristic polynomial $\lambda^2 - 2\lambda - 4$, and then the Cayley-Hamilton theorem implies $A_n = 2 A_{n-1} + 4 A_{n-2}$ and similarly for $B, C$.

Comment: Oh wait, the characteristic polynomial is probably $(\lambda+2)(\lambda^2 - 2\lambda - 4)$ given the eigenvector $(1, -1, 0)$.  So it's a little more complex than that, but not by that much.

Answer (score 3):

Lulu has shown that $a_n$ obeys the recursive equation
$$
a_n=2a_{n-1}+4a_{n-2}.
$$
I can give a combinatorial proof of this recurrence. I was only able to derive this in hindsight, because I could come up with a recurrence relation by thinking combinatorially.

Valid sequences of length $n$, where $n\ge 2$, fall into two disjoint classes.

1. The first class contains sequences where both of the last symbols are nonzero, OR where the last two symbols are either "$01$" or "$02$", in that order. 

   There are exactly $2a_{n-1}$ sequences in this class. Given a valid sequence of length $n-1$, there are two ways to extend it to a sequence in this class. If the shorter sequences ends with $1,2,3,$ or $4,$ then there are two ways to extend it with a nonzero number. If the shorter sequence ends with $0$, then it can only be extended by $1$ or $2$.
2. The second class contains everything not covered by the first class. This means there is at least one zero in the last two symbols, excepting sequences ending with $01$ or $02$. 

   You can then show that the number of remaining sequences is $4a_{n-2}$. Again, every sequence in this class is uniquely determined by taking a valid sequence of length $n-2$, then extending it in one of four ways. This is best explained by the table below.

| If the sequence of length $n-2$ ends with... | then the four options for extension are... |
| --- | --- |
| $1$ | $03,04,30,40.$ |
| $2$ | $03,04,30,40.$ |
| $3$ | $03,04,10,20.$ |
| $4$ | $03,04,10,20.$ |
| $0$ | $10,20,30,40.$ |

Comment: Thanks for this!